# CSS: Center a main page div

Tags: html, css, web

I have a layout in mind for my website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyVVF.jpg
The problem is, I have no idea how to make the center strip  go behind the nav bar, stay toward the middle of the page (even when zooming),  or even show up the right way. Can someone either direct me to a tutorial, or tell me how? Here is my full code: http://jsfiddle.net/c7r6g/ (I have set the navbar as image files, if you didn't notice)
The navbar is `.rounded`, and the div I'm trying to center is `#centerstrip`

Sorry if this is a bit vague, I am an amateur in CSS (Especially positioning.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made changes in your CSS,this works fine in your fiddle,replace that in your fiddle with this.

```
#centerstrip {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

By this your div will be aligned to center and your div will be underneath the nav bar also.

Comment: This is what I get when I use your code:http://imgur.com/54DuhIS What browser are you using? It doesn't work for me in firefox or chrome.

Comment: I viewed it in chrome and made the necessary changes,try now.

Comment: ah you forgot to write some text in `centerstrip` div,try that. It will definitely work.

Comment: `<div ID="centerstrip">
        some text
 </div>`

Comment: Thank you! Almost done, I want it to be able to go under the navbar, and have the logo (which in theory, will be part of the centerstrip) above the navbar. Would there be a way to do this, or should I just have a small empty space between the navbar and centerstrip, and have the logo above the navbar? (I hope that made sense!)

Comment: (sorry about the late reply) @Sid

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CSS z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). With it you can define which element is placed on top of the other.

If you add this to the style of your `#centerstrip`, it'll display underneath the navigation bar.

```
#centerstrip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That's much better, thank you. One problem I have, though, is that when zoomed out in the browser, it stays the same size, and doesn't stay to the center. Is there a fix that you know of for that?

Answer (score 0):

Since your navbar is part of your content, all you have to do is make it extend to the outsides, which can be done by having its width be greater than 100%. This will make it extend to the right of the main content.

To shift it left, you have two options, both of which have their merits:
1. Shift the navbar to the left by using a position of relative and a negative left value.
2. Use a negative margin on the left hand side.

This will allow you to avoid using the z-index, which may not be fruitful since the navbar is part of the center strip.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do what you're saying. Should I set the width of the UL to be greater than 100%? Because I have pixel information for each button on the navbar. Also, I'm happy with my navbar, but not with the center strip that's supposed to be behind it. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I usually wrap everything in the body inside a div and then center the div. The body element naturally will have a width equal to whatever your browser window is, so therefore if you the first tag inside your body tag is a div, and you center that div, it will be centered to the body and thus the window. Here's some sample code:

```
<!doctype HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta lang="en" charset="utf-8" /> 
            <title>Sample</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
            </div>

            <style>
                body{
                    background-color: red;
                }
                #container{
                    height: 400px;
                    width: 400px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    background-color: blue;
                } 
            </style>

        </body>
    </html>
```

The trick is to use `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;`, and to be sure that you're putting that style on a div. You can't put that style on the body because the body has nothing to reference itself against for centering. A div however, can center itself in relation to the width of the body

Answer (score 0):

Just messing around a bit, here you go. I managed to render your linked image in CSS.

While I am using just divs, the concept are the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/jqarz/1/

Code below.

A couple concepts to explore are width, margin and padding. It's important to note that width is actually "width of the content box" and not width of the element, like many sites poorly describe it.

There are a lot of ways to do this and this is just one, it's really dependent on what you are trying to do and with what.

HTML:

```
<div id="background">

    <div id="navbar">navbar</div>
    <div id="content"></div>    

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background
{
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #CFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#content
{
    z-index: 1;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #FFC;
}

#navbar
{ 
    top: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FCF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend using the

```
.property{
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Where the number indicates the highest element in a z array-like position.

Also, if you want it to keep the same way with different resolutions and zooms, try responsive design.

May I recommend also if you're going to get into responsive design, taking a look at some really good frameworks such as bootstrap or foundation.